# How to send data from client to server

Tags: php, file, server

I'm trying to write a server, which can download files in a piece-wise manner. So, if the connection is interrupted, next time the same client connects, the download can resume from where it stopped.

Now, suppose when the client opens the webpage, the server starts reading files saved on it, in the following manner:

```
$handle = fopen($file_in, "rb");
$handle_2 = fopen($file_out, "w");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($file_in));
fwrite($handle_2, $contents);
```

Of course, the fwrite won't work with files on the client's computer.

So basically my question is, how do I send data to a file on the client's pc, once I have the file contents?

Comment: This package seems to support partial downloads: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-download.intro.php

Comment: Nice, just the thing I needed. Make it an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTTP_Download PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-download.intro.php) seems to be what you are looking for:

> HTTP_Download provides an interface to easily send any arbitrary data
>   to HTTP clients. HTTP_Download can gain its data from variables, files
>   or stream resources.
>
> With this package you can easily handle (hidden) downloads. Hidden
>   means not accessible by the public - for instance if you want to
>   restrict access to particular downloads.
>
> It supports HTTP compression, caching and partial downloads, resuming
>   and sending raw data, for example from database BLOBs.